# How do I do a htaccess wildcard redirect for all pages begining with a numeral

Tags: redirect, seo, wildcard

I have a customer who had an indexible IDX attached to his site where the entire MLS for Phoenix was indexed as though each listing were a page on his site. We pulled the plug on this over a year ago but still get 900 404 redirects. Is there some code I can put into his .htacess file that will redirect all of these pages to his home page? Each one of these bogus pages begins with a numeral so if there is a wildcard that I can use that will redirect any page e.g. http://homesaleaz.com/2394emainstreet/ to the home page? I think this indexible IDX was caught by Google and think his site is suffering for this blackhat SEO.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Enable .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]+ /
```